# insert pdf file into mobile app development

Tags: codenameone

I have a pdf file of a map of the building and I want to attach this map into the app. How can I do it? I try to convert the pdf file into the URL and use action event in the button but it didn't work. I also screenshot the map and attach the picture into the button but it is too large and I can't zoom in the detail in the map. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by action event but Display's `execute` should display a `file` or `https` URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image an then place it with an `ImageViewer`. That allows pinch to zoom on the device so you can see the finer details.